# Protect Custom Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, javascript, json

I had developed my very own custom chrome extension and sell it to my clients.

But clients saying that the protection wasn't good enough due to their users are still able to remove and disable the extension.

Is there anyway to prevent it?

Or maybe there is a way to detect if the extension is disable/uninstall?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone to respond?

Answer (score 0):

If the extension is not available on the Chrome Web Store, 
then each client (and their users) would have to be on an Active Directory domain; 
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist

Comment: Nope. The extension is custom made and is not going to put at Chrome Store. I have read about the ExtensionInstallForceList, but I couldn't find any example on how to achieve that. Please advise, thanks